# Are tags that refer to concepts, rather than technologies, searched for as often as technology tags?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Looked at a question just now that was tagged "MySQL", "rolling-average" and I realised that I seldom, if ever, search for tags that describe concepts but I use technology tags all the time

Is there any available info on how often abstract tags are searched for, compared to technology tags? If technology tags are searched/subscribed to orders of magnitudes more often, is there much point (from an OP's promote-my-question-to-an-audience perspective) in tagging questions with abstract/concept tags?

Comment: Not sure if there's any public data on "tag searching", but MySQL (and any other technologies) are broad, and tags usually give the overview/main topic of the question (i.e. question categorization). For answerer, I only know the basic query of MySQL, so I won't probably open questions tagged with [tag:rolling-average] because I won't be able to understand nor answer it...

Comment: Interesting point; so you might only ever search for technology tags but use the concept tags to judge whether the question is answerable by you?

Comment: Pretty much yes, unless I'm challenged enough to learn about the concept and try to answer it. For moderation, it's also easier to find duplicate questions if questions are properly tagged, including the concept tags.